# react-select : show only the matched options on typing on the select input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have started using react-select very recently.
(https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

If the select input is blank and 
 1. I focus on the select input OR, 
 2. I click on the inverted arrow situated at the right side of the
    select input, I get to see all the options in the result list that I
    have supplied to the Select component by default.

Instead of the above mentioned behavior, I should only be able to see the matched text results when I type something on the input. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

Control the rendering of the menu with menuIsOpen prop and add custom event handlers for onInputChange, onChange and onBlur: `onInputChange` you just check if the action performed is input-change and then set `openMenu` (in the component state) to true; `onChange` and `onBlur` events you just hide the menu.

```
<Select
    inputValue={value}
    onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
    onChange={this.hideMenu}
    onBlur={this.hideMenu}
    options={dataSource}
    menuIsOpen={openMenu}
/>
```

```
    handleInputChange = (query, { action }) => {
        if (action === "input-change") {
            this.setState({ openMenu: true });
        }
    };
```

```
hideMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ openMenu: false });
};
```

Source : https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2014#issuecomment-448549849

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the arrow by giving a `arrowRenderer` with value `null`, and only make it so that options show up when typing by disabling open on focus and click:

**Example**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Select
      arrowRenderer={null}
      options={[{ value: 1, label: "foo" }, { value: 2, label: "bar" }]}
      openOnFocus={false}
      openOnClick={false}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. These options worked perfectly well for first time when I focused on the input, but the moment I clicked on the input again.. the options showed up immediately, although the input was still blank. Is there a way to make sure that the options should never get displayed when the input is blank?

Comment: @Wenger That's frustrating. That [seems to be an open issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2014) that has no real fix in `react-select` yet.